# Can't share text to fb messenger using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios9, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-share

I can share text to whatsapp/message app using

```
NSString* text=@"I am sharing this text";
NSArray* sharedArray=@[text];
UIActivityViewController * activityVC=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:sharedArray applicationActivities:nil];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // code here
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];//:activityVC animated:YES];

});
```

BUt the facebook messenger option is missing when I use this piece of code.

I have to add NSURL to the array, to make the facebook messenger option visible in the `UIActivityController` view:

```
NSString* text=@"I am sharing this text";
NSURL *myWebsite = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSArray* sharedArray=@[text,myWebsite];
UIActivityViewController * activityVC=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:sharedArray applicationActivities:nil];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // code here
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];//:activityVC animated:YES];

});
```

But the issue is, the text is not shared in the facebook messenger, only the link gets shared to fb-messenger.

Is there a way to share text to fb-messenger from our app ?

Comment: In this way i also try for Whats app sharing only text. in iOS 9 but not share only text. this isuue is occur =>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760970/uiactivityviewcontroller-share-text-in-whats-app-and-all-sharing-option

Answer (score 3):

According to [Facebook's Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) you unfortunately can no longer provide pre-fill text for sharing. This is why sharing with text silently fails. Who knows, if enough people complain they might change this, but I wouldn't hold your breath!