# Facebook Messenger not showing up with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-messenger

I am using UIActivityViewController in my app to provide options for users to share some text. [image]

Apps like facebook, twitter, whatsapp once installed they automatically show up as options with UIActivityViewController, but not Facebook Messenger.

Any special set up I need to do with Messenger? I am using objective c.

Comment: were you able to find anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to: [Can't share text to fb messenger using UIActivityViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36070512/cant-share-text-to-fb-messenger-using-uiactivityviewcontroller)

In order to make Facebook Messenger appear you need to insert NSURL into UIActivityViewController activityItems

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
NSArray *activityItems = @[url];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
```